# Lightshot - change save folder (Windows 10)

Tags: screenshot, recent-items

I would like [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/) to save screenshots to desktop, how do I do that?

Tutorials I found doesn't seem to touch on that.

At some point, I selected a folder to save a screenshot from Lightshot. Since then, all screens save there. I **found** that folder by [Recent files view](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/recent_files_view.html), but that tool doesn't allow me to change (or simply delete) Lightshot default saves folder - or I don't know how it allows me to do so.

When I delete **found** folder, Lightshot makes it again.

I tried reinstalling Lightshot, but it remembered the saves folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Lightshot's [website](https://app.prntscr.com/en/hotkeys.html), it says that `Ctrl`+`S` hotkey saves the screenshot to the most recent folder.

To change it, do not use the hotkey for the first time. Instead, click on the **Save** button and save the screenshot to wherever you want. After that, all screenshots will be automatically saved to that folder with any hotkey.

I tested it and it works.

Comment: Wow, didn't think of that button and hotkey could have different functionality. It is their fault really. When you hover over the icon it says `Save (Ctrl + S)` implying they are equivalent!

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot access the default screenshot folder to get your images (Windows 10 x64):

1. Retake a screenshot
2. Press save
3. Instead of saving send all your screenshots 1 by 1 to desktop with right click > Send to> Desktop (Create shortcut)
4. Open shortcuts 1 by 1 and save the images in your preferred folder.

Do not save in default folder (Windows 10 x64). Try a folder on your Desktop or anywhere else but the default path.